# Searching shared libraries in Linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld, elf

please explain me why on x86_64 Scientific Linux no file under */etc/ld.so.conf.d* contains the directory */usr/lib64*?

The list of directories to be searched by program loader is stored in the file /etc/ld.so.conf. On my distributive, this file stores this row: *include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf*
And the above directory consists of:

```
[root@dev_host build]$ ls -la /etc/ld.so.conf.d
total 36
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Aug 29 23:13 .
drwxr-xr-x. 103 root root 12288 Sep 18 03:41 ..
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    17 Mar 20  2012 atlas-x86_64.conf
-r--r--r--.   1 root root   324 May  7 23:40 kernel-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64.conf
-r--r--r--.   1 root root   324 Nov 22  2013 kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.conf
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    17 Feb 12  2014 mysql-x86_64.conf
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    31 Aug 11 14:46 postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf -> /etc/alternatives/pgsql-ld-conf
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    22 Sep  7  2011 qt-x86_64.conf
```

I examined all these files - there is no /usr/lib64. Why? Is it stored in /etc/ld.so.cache?

Comment: Your ld.so may be built to support `/usr/lib64` by default. Check `strings /lib/ld*.so | fgrep /usr/lib64`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's. But command is: strings /lib64/ld*.so | fgrep /usr/lib64

Comment: Yes you are right, that should be the command.